# Include tag wiki content when searching on tags page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, search

When doing a search on [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), can tag wiki (or tag wiki excerpt) content be included?

I was searching on tags for "remote branch" and only got [remote-branch](/questions/tagged/remote-branch) which was used 103 times and lacked a tag wiki, which suggested that maybe it was a bad tag, and there could be some more suitable tag out there which I can't find.

Comment: You mean you want tag wiki content to be *searched* as well, right? If so, this might be incredibly noisy unless we account for relevance there, which would probably require a substantial amount of work. I'm not entirely sure this is worth it right now. In your case, the only tag this would have picked up is `git`, which you probably new to include anyway.

Comment: In conversation yesterday, I had the same thought as this request - to me it makes a lot of sense to include, not the Wiki, but the excerpt as part of the tag search, both when searching tags generally and when askers (or editors) are trying to tag questions. For that reason, I'm going to status-review this request. This doesn't mean we'll build it as there may be performance issues with searching more than the tags themselves that I can't predict but I feel like it's at minimum worth investigating.

Comment: We're going to investigate the feasibility of this in a future sprint but we don't have a specific timeline or outcome.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a new feature, you can do this via the Data Explorer.

[Here is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402952/finding-tag-by-excerpt-contents) that gets free text contents as input, and is searching all excerpts for those contents, then returning the matching tags.

As Thomas also mentioned in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/include-tag-wiki-content-when-searching-on-tags-page#comment875758_270154), for your sample search of "remote branch" only one matching tag which is [git-track](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-track).