# Community post-bumping rampage on meta.SFF

Tags: bug, community-user, bump

UPDATE: After 12 hours of post-bumping Community seems to have gone back into hibernation. Sorry for the noise(?).

---

I know that the Community "user" sometimes bumps posts that have [sat unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) for a while, to get them more attention.

However, over the ten hours or so, Community has been bumping posts on [meta.scifi.stackexchange.com](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/) at the rate of about one per hour, which is far, far more often than I've ever seen before. At least one of them is a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) bug report from 2012 and the timeline views seem to suggest that some of them already had upvoted answers (though I might be misinterpreting it).

e.g. [this timeline](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/1249/timeline) says that this post had two upvotes as of 13 hours ago, but [its question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/accepted-answer-image-is-cut-off) was bumped 9 hours ago?

As another example: [this question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/is-there-a-feature-page-where-i-can-see-all-the-questions-under-my-favourite-tag/6490#6490) was just bumped 45 minutes ago; according to [its timeline](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/6489/timeline) and the [timeline for it's one answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/6490/timeline) it's had no activity since Jan 25, 2015.
Is this normal?

Comment: Most likely all the votes have been cast after the bump, no bug there. The timeline is showing only a daily summary, the timestamp is of 12 AM, not actual time of voting. The weird part is why it started bumping now.

Comment: If someone is going through old meta posts and voting on them, any question whose single answer they downvote from 1 vote to 0 votes will soon get bumped by Community.  Ask me how I know...

Comment: That's an idea I can look into; there is unfortunately something many of these questions have in common but I haven't checked them all.

Comment: Given the controversy surrounding their recent moderator election, there may well be more activity on Meta.SFF than usual. Which might lead to people answering old posts and then deleting their answers again, or other situations that lead to a bump.

Comment: so, if there were a ton of posts now eligible for bumping, is "once an hour" the usual rate at which that happens?

Comment: @S.L.Barth no, when an answer is deleted, it's showing its author as the "modified by", not Community.  (unless the user account is deleted)

Comment: It looks like some of these questions have answers from deleted accounts (user56 and user1027). The first of these asked to have his/her account deleted, out of disagreement with the election result. So, maybe recent account deletions affected the score and caused the bumps?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I thought the deleted accounts were the missing link (though I was concerned about something a bit more nefarious) but I just checked http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/6489/timeline and *nothing* has happened to that post or it's 1 answer since Jan 25, 2015

Comment: There's always the chance there was a bug causing the auto-bump to crash, and after it was fixed (e.g. server restart) it just started working as expected again. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wouldn't that affect multiple sites? AFAIK meta.SFF does not have a server of its own.

Comment: @S.L.Barth dunno, maybe each site has its own thread in the auto bump process - one unhandled exception, and the thread is killed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ...and since moderators are human exception handlers, the new hypothesis is that a new, inexperienced moderator failed to handle an exception :-D

Comment: I've seen questions **here** get bumped even though they have red tags... I don't think the tags prevent Community from bumping... though they probably should.

Comment: @Catija http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-posts-with-a-status-tag-when-bumping

Comment: @ShadowWizard Meh.. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/include-tag-wiki-content-when-searching-on-tags-page) got bumped a few days ago and no SE person even posted an answer, so how is it supposed to get voted on?

Comment: @Catija they don't, I knew that, it was just pointing out that it's highly unlikely the post had any recent changes that would qualify it to suddenly be bumped.

Comment: For the status-completed post, I can say that one of the upvotes was mine and that I upvoted it after it got bumped. At that time, it had a score of 0 (well, 1 after I voted). – Are upvotes from an account removed when that account is deleted? That could explain it; the answers to the bumped questions may have had upvotes only from the deleted accounts, so they went back to 0 score after the accounts were removed.

Comment: I admit I am judging almost entirely based on the timeline, which may not show all relevant information