# Tag excerpt is missing when searching tags?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt, tag-search

The tag excerpt seems to be missing when searching for tags from [the Tags page](/tags).

> [image]

I believe it was working previously, while only tag synonyms that don't show the excerpt.

Tried on Chrome 113 in incognito mode on Windows 10, but I think this issue is independent of the browser and OS.

---

*This is not a duplicate of [Include tag wiki content when searching on tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/include-tag-wiki-content-when-searching-on-tags-page) where it asked about searching for tag excerpt & wiki.*